# Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton

Tags: react-native

I try to create navigation with `{ createStackNavigator, createAppContainer  }` from `react-navigation` but when a start my application I always get an error. I can't find any documentation or help on this.

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{ 
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js", 
  "scripts": { 
    "start": "expo start", 
    "android": "expo start --android", 
    "ios": "expo start --ios", 
    "eject": "expo eject" 
    }, 
  "dependencies": { 
    "expo": "^32.0.0", 
    "react": "16.5.0", 
    "react-native": "github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
     "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15", 
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9" 
    }, 
  "devDependencies": { 
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0" 
    }, 
  "private": true 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Note this answer was written for Expo v33. Please check with the current documentation for react-navigation and the version of Expo that you are using for up-to-date installation instructions.

The reason for your error is that you are using `react-navigation` in your Expo app, however you have followed the tutorial incorrectly.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

If you read the instructions it tells you that once you have installed `react-navigation` you should then install `react-native-gesture-handler`. However that is not what they say

> Next, install react-native-gesture-handler. If you’re using Expo you
> don’t need to do anything here, it’s included in the SDK.

It says that if you are using `Expo` you do not need to install `react-native-gesture-handler` as it is already installed.

You are getting errors because you have installed `react-native-gesture-handler`, it already exists in Expo, and Expo is getting confused about where to get its information from.

To solve your problem do the following.

1. Close all terminals running `Expo`
2. Close the browser window running `Expo`
3. Clear the project you were working on from the `Expo` app on your device.
4. Delete your `package-lock.json`
5. Delete your `node_modules` folder
6. Remove the `react-native-gesture-handler` entry from your `package.json`
7. Run `npm i`
8. Restart `Expo` using `expo start -c`

Be careful when using `Expo` it is easy to install dependencies that cannot run with it, and cause yourself issues like this.

Comment: Andrew, I followed all your steps but still getting same error in my project. could you please help or should I ask new question on SO? https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/exchange-o-gram/commits/master

Comment: Using expo so i have not installed react-native-gesture-handler separately. But still i am getting same error

Comment: Excellent - this still works for expo v40

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who gets here searching for:
***"Unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js""***

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5107

If you're using Expo SDK 34+, despite what older threads says, you need to run the following to get it working:
`expo install react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: I followed Andrew's steps above and then Victor's and now my project works again. I am running expo v39.0.2

Answer (score 4):

There is a conflict between the installed react-native gesture-handler package and another pulled in as a dependency of a different package installed, the two packages are definitely different versions.

**Solution?** Go to your package-lock.json and find react-native-gesture-handler instances. Find the one pulled in as a dependency of a different package i.e in my case:

```
 node_modules/@rainbow-me/animated-charts/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler": {
       3027       "version": "1.10.3",
 "}
```

This was pulling in the offending react-native-gesture-handler package. Go to node_modules and delete that version of the react-native-gesture-handler, then restart your server.

Comment: I had just installed @rainbow-me/animated-charts and that was the issue. After deleting it from the node_modules the error was gone. Thanks!

Comment: This should be picked as the correct answer. This solves the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @YaronLevi Exactly! This solves the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

going off of [@Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488122/3942699), the issue may sometimes even be a little subtler than an extraneous manual install of `react-native-gesture-handler`: for me, i found out that a package i updated recently included their own copy of `react-native-gesture-handler` as a dependency (found out by doing a search through my `yarn.lock`, `package-lock.json`, `node_modules`, etc.) - so i had to downgrade that package to a version that wasn't dependent on `react-native-gesture-handler`..

Answer (score 3):

So I'm using expo SDK32 and had the same issue.

I tried:

1. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` with no luck.
2. Removing `react-native-gesture-handler` from your `package.json` and doing `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` with no luck...

I had success by making sure my version of `react-native-gesture-handler` was only allowing patch changes in the semver.

**old package.json line** *(when name collision error was happening)*:

`"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",`

*(The `^` here tells npm to bump to highest minor version, which installed version `1.4.1`)*

**new package.json line** *(fixed the error for me)*:

`"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.0.12",`

*(The `~` here tells npm to only bump the highest patch version, which installed `1.0.17` and the error was gone)*

I'm assuming some kind of collision was happening having different minor versions?

I think this is what [@feihcsim was talking about in their answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55766682/4612939)

Comment: I don't know exactly how the versions did crash the app (my problem was with react-native-safe-area-context) but changing from `^` to `~` saved me. 
Thank you!

Comment: awesome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are NOT using expo and saw this error, then you may be using a component which return's a **TouchableOpacity**. You may get the same error and several script bundling will also happen. To fix that wrap the TouchableOpacity within a **View**.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using expo and I had the same problem. I fixed it by going into my `package-lock.json` file and find `react-native-gesture-handler` and removed the whole package with dependencies.
After this, in node_modules folder I deleted the folder named `react-native-gesture-handler`.
now, `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`
worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

###### For expo try this:

expo install react-native-safe-area-context 
yarn or npm install

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo to build your react native app you do not have to import react-native-gesture-handler from npm or yarn. It is already in the expo package. If you import the package you will experience this error.

Answer (score 0):

For **non-Expo applications**, the above-given solution does work out.
So, for ***react-native applications*** made in **ANDROID Studio** here is the solution:-

- Replace your **react-native-linked** dependency version with its
  the latest version currently latest is **2.1.1** which gives this error,
  replace it with this link - [version](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin.git)
  "https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin.git" along with
  required changes.
- Delete and reinstall node_module.
- After installing, either delete the **WEBVIEW** folder from
  "react-native-linked" in node_module manually or write the below the
  line in your script in the package.json file:
  `"postinstall": "npx jetifier; patch-package; rm -rf ./node_modules/react-native-linkedin/node_modules/react-native-webview",`  after "start" key.

Answer (score 0):

I use expo 45 and as I see in the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486525/tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rngesturehandlerbutton),
I need to run

`expo install react-native-gesture-handler`,

then add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` in `App.js` and then I can import and use it anywhere like:

```js
import { TapGestureHandler, RotationGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class ComponentName extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TapGestureHandler>
        <RotationGestureHandler>...</RotationGestureHandler>
      </TapGestureHandler>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you should make sure that the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` specified in your project's root matches the version used by the dependent npm modules.

1. Check the version of `react-native-gesture-handler` in your project's root.
2. Now, go through your project's npm modules and ensure that they are using the same version.
3. If you discover a version mismatch, update the dependent module's version of `react-native-gesture-handler` to match the version in your project's root.

Answer (score -1):

I have an expo project

It seems the problem was with react-native-safe-area-context

All I did was-

`yarn add react-native-safe-area-context`

and it worked(I already had it installed but I guess Yarn resolved some other issues for me)

Answer (score -1):

One other solution for @rainbow-me/animated-charts

Go to ***package-lock.json*** and see the version of gesture handler

---

"node_modules/@rainbow-me/animated-charts": {
. . .
"dependencies": {
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
},

---

then go to ***package.json*** and replace the version
"dependencies": {
. . .
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.7.0"
},

In terminal issue **npm update**

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me after I encountered this error.

You are getting errors because you have installed react-native-gesture-handler, it already exists in Expo, and Expo is getting confused about where to get its information from.

how to fix this:

1. Stop the server (ctrl+c)
2. Run this on your terminal:

   npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler
3. Then re-run the server using npm start