# React Native - Package imports FlatList from "gesture-handler" and causes an error, when changing import from "react-native" scrolling does not work

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm trying to add the following package to my project but it causes the error:

**'Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton",**

which it doesn't do in my other project and I don't know why.
When I change the import of FlatList from "react-native-gesture-handler", and change to from "react-native" the error mentions but it doesn't work scrolling the list

**The package I'm trying to get working:**

https://github.com/Bur0/react-native-actions-sheet-picker

**Link to changed file where scrolling does not work (On github it is located in /src/components/Picker.tsx):**

https://controlc.com/9b7a0988

Answer (score 0):

I installed "react-native-gesture-handler" unnecessarily.
Just uninstall it since I use expo and this package is already in it.
See answer:
[Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486525/tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rngesturehandlerbutton)