# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo React Native app, and I'm facing two different errors based on whether I have `react-native-gesture-handler` installed or not (packages: [`react-native-wagmi-charts`](https://github.com/coinjar/react-native-wagmi-charts) and/or [`react-native-graph`](https://github.com/margelo/react-native-graph)).

Without `react-native-gesture-handler` installed:
When I don't include the react-native-gesture-handler package (expo install react-native-gesture-handler), I encounter the following error during Android bundling:

```js
Android Bundling failed 6873ms
Unable to resolve module react-native-gesture-handler from C:\...\pricetracker\node_modules\react-native-wagmi-charts\src\charts\candle\Crosshair.tsx: react-native-gesture-handler could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
   6 |   LongPressGestureHandlerEventPayload,
   7 |   LongPressGestureHandlerProps,
>  8 | } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
     |         ^
   9 | import Animated, {
  10 |   useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  11 |   useSharedValue,
› Reloading apps
Android Bundling complete 2701ms
Android Running app on sdk_gphone_x86_64
```

With `react-native-gesture-handler` installed:
When I do include the react-native-gesture-handler package (expo install react-native-gesture-handler), I encounter the following error related to an "Invariant Violation":

```js
Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton, js engine: hermes
```

I'm unsure how to proceed with resolving these issues. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solves the root cause of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70684652/12640100

> There is a conflict between the installed react-native gesture-handler
> package and another pulled in as a dependency of a different package
> installed, the two packages are definitely different versions.
>
> **Solution?** Go to your package-lock.json and find react-native-gesture-handler instances. Find the one pulled in as a
> dependency of a different package i.e in my case:
>
> ```
>  node_modules/@rainbow-me/animated-charts/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler":
> ```
>
> {
> 3027       "version": "1.10.3",
> "}
>
> This was pulling in the offending react-native-gesture-handler
> package. Go to node_modules and delete that version of the
> react-native-gesture-handler, then restart your server.